# Invalid json stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a tool to build a dynamic table:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <hr>
      <h3>Insert your data</h3>
      <button id="addTd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Column
      </button>
      <button id="addTr" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Row
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="saveTable">Save table</button>
      <hr>
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button>
              <br>
              <input class="form-control column_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name"  value="Hello">
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tr_clone">
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeRow">Delete row</button></td>
            <td><input class="form-control row_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="data" name="who" value="Bye"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2>
        Rebuild table
      </h2>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

When I hit save, it generates a json and the rebuilds the table:

```
$('#saveTable').on("click", function() {

   var results={};
   $('thead input').each(function(){
    results[$(this).val()] = [];
   });

   var resultsKeys = Object.keys(results);

   $('tbody input').each(function(){
    var colIndex = $(this).parent().index();

    var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();

    results[resultsKeys[colIndex-1]].push($(this).val());
   });


   rebuild(results);

});

function rebuild(results) {
  var data = "[" + JSON.stringify(results) +"]";
  console.log(data);

  data.forEach(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      $('thead').append($('<th>').text(key));

      obj[key].forEach((e, i) => {
        if(!$("tbody tr:eq("+i+")").length) $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody"));
        $("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")").append($('<td>').text(e))
      })
    })
  });
}

    $('#table-data input').on("change", function() {
      $(this).attr("value", $(this).attr("value"));
    });

    $(".table-striped tbody tr th input").each(function(){
      $(this).addClass("column_data");
    });

    $("#addTr").on('click', function() {
      var $tr    = $('tbody tr.tr_clone');
      var $clone = $tr.clone();
      $clone.find(':text').val('');
      $tr.after($clone);
      $(".table-striped tbody tr td input").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("row_data");
      });
    });

    $("#addTd").on("click", function(){
      $(".table-striped thead tr").append('<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button><br><input class="form-control" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name"></th>');
      $(".table-striped tbody tr").append('</td> <td><input type="text" placeholder="data" name="datepicker_end" class="form-control"></td>');
      $(document).find("thead th input").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("column_data");
      });
      $(".table-striped tbody tr td input").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("row_data");
      });
    });

        $(document).on("click", ".removeRow", function(){
     $(this).parent().parent()
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".removeColumn", function(){
      var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
      $(this).closest("table").find("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").remove();
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

But that's giving me:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

[jsFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/47/)

Comment: You should be testing if the item is an array with `Array.isArray` before you call your `forEach`

Comment: but when I do `console.log(data);` it is giving me the correct json string `[{"Hello":["Bye"]}]`

Comment: Add `Array.isArray(data) &&` before `data.forEach(...` removes the error, and the code still works.

Comment: I updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/62/)... But I'm too unsure about what you wish to achieve to continue...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks, in reality I will send the json to the database and then call it on page load, the table building tool will be in the cms, while the rebuild table bit will be on a page

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that's quite wrong, try to click save button https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/62/

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette bingo! https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/74/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem there is that data is a string and not an array.

```
Use data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: @no worries thank you, yet it is not providing all the values https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/62/

Comment: uhm...  Why would you use JSON.parse rather than removing JSON.stringify that immediately preceded it? The foreach seems rather pointless anyway, there's only one item.

Comment: That Works algo @Kevin.